# not allowing the user to input the numeric digits in a field

Tags: regex, validation, jquery-validate

I have an input field and i want that no user can input any numeric digits in the field...how would i do it.?the input field should not take any special characters also except ampersand(&),and can accept spaces.

Comment: what you have tried ? Have u searched Regex on Google ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a character class with beginning and end anchors to specify what is allowed:

```
/^[a-z& ]*$/i
```

Allows:

- A-Z (case insensitive)
- & (ampersand)
- spaces

0 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

This checks that there are no numbers in the string:

```
/[^0-9]*/
```

Comment: I just want to note remus answer is correct. I'm just showing the general way to accept with just no numbers.